# ROS have a Scara robot packages?

Tags: ros, robot, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello. In my lab there is a scara robot i would like to work with it using ros. I like to known if exist a packages in ros using a scara or something similar. thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142486/ros-have-a-scara-robot-packages?/) by [coughsyrup](https://answers.ros.org/users/4962/coughsyrup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-20**:
Do you know the manufacturer and model of your robot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think there is only support for articulated robots currently. But you should check the list here:
http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/supported_hardware

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-21**:
The URDF format should be flexible enough to model a SCARA robot without problems. The bigger question is finding drivers that can control and read the hardware from ROS.

**Comment by [coughsyrup](https://answers.ros.org/users/4962/coughsyrup/) on 2014-03-21**:
well we have the drivers the we can use and we are thinking using a raspberry pi. i saw in the gazebo simulator package in groovy the they have a scara in the example kit you think i can use that scara or i have to build my own scara package.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-21**:
You can probably adapt the existing SCARA model to your robot. If you're going to be doing any kind of motion planning, you'll need to make sure that the dimensions in your URDF match your robot.